# I get an odd 401 response preforming a get, linkedin API

Tags: c#, linkedin-api

This gives me the proper response:

`"https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~?oauth2_access_token="+AToken;`

This gives a 401.... not sure why.

`"http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/url=www.linkedin.com%2Fin%2Fpersoniamusing?oauth2_access_token="+AToken`

the exception I catch:

`System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.
   at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadDataInternal(Uri address, WebRequest& request)`

Comment: Can you provide the exact request and response (for example from a tool like Fiddler)?

Comment: The message you get from the response would be more helpful here. When I plug in those URL's I get a 401 as well but the message lets me know why exactly it returned a 401. So the full response would be ideal.