# Testing in two different places gives me two different HTTP responses. LinkedIn

Tags: c#, json, linkedin-api

I have a `GET` request.

One preforming in C# like so

```
      public void MssGetPictureURL(string ssPublicLinkedinURL, out string ssPictureURL, string ssAccessToken){

        try{
            using (var client = new WebClient()){
                var responseString = client.DownloadString("https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.linkedin.com%2Fin%2Fsomeperson:(picture-url)?format=json&oauth2_access_token=" + ssAccessToken);
                var ResponceArray = responseString.Split('"', '{', '}', ',');
                ssPictureURL = responseString;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            ssPictureURL = e.ToString();
        }

    }
```

in `apigee.com` i am preforming the same `GET`:

`https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.linkedin.com%2Fin%2Fsomeperson:(picture-url)?format=json&oauth2_access_token=` + `whatever the token they have`

this makes no sense to me why they would give me different responses. the `apigee` gives the proper `json` response, the `GET` request from my code gives me a `400`.... The wierder thing is that when i change to:

`https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(picture-url)?format=json&oauth2_access_token=" + ssAccessToken);` (this gets the users profile pic) this works fine in both places!!!!

here is the `json` response:

```
 {
  "errorCode": 0,
  "message": "Unknown field {} in resource {Person}",
  "requestId": "HRR4WP2Y4E",
  "status": 400,
  "timestamp": 1400099795729
   }
```

Any help on what to do would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Just like the other question you asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23657187/i-get-an-odd-401-response-preforming-a-get-linkedin-api, seeing the response would probably be helpful.

Comment: @BenBlack added the response, sorry, didn't see your comment on my other post.

Answer (score 1):

Could be linkedin detecting UA-headers or similar and acting different. Try sending the requests to a URL you control yourself and examine the request headers... I'd look at the user agent header first.